# Maintenance of cucumber features by non-technical people

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, git

I have written a framework containing cucumber steps and their Java implementation using Selenium.

They're generic enough for the application so that a user can now write new features **using Gherkin** without having the necessity to change anything in the underlaying Java code.

But I have a little question.

What is the best way to make the framework maintainable (*so basically CRUD on feature files*) by the functional testers that are no technical people?

Some additions :

1. The framework is hosted on a VCS
2. It should be able to run using Jenkins
3. The feature files are within the framework (on the VCS thus)

Are there already frameworks doing this? Or will I have to write my own web-client modifying the testing framework repository?

Comment: What things in the framework you would like the functional tests to maintain? Refactor API? Examples would be helpful.

Comment: @dzieciou Basically adding new tests bu writing new feature files, or modify existing ones, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it too much to ask the non-technical staff to get familiar with the basics of your repo management tools? This would have a few benefits:

- They could keep things simple by using branch, checkout, add, commit, push. It's a new skill for them to learn so they may be happy to get that experience.
- You (or other techies) could review their pull requests, and, you could see issues arising at they happen, for example if multiple steps are used instead of a composite step. You'd be a gatekeeper, and if all looks good, you merge, otherwise you can easily comment in the code review tool you are using.
- No need for yet another tool, which would need to be created, configured, maintained, etc.

My main thought is that giving non-techies full access to update the feature files could result in the scenarios getting out of control. I think having a gatekeeper (a techie who is familiar with steps and the underlying way things work) would be critical to maintain high quality.

I've seen in the past where non-techies update source code along with the feature files. That's a slippery slope and hard to break that culture if it is established without offending people. So, do whatever you can to avoid that from happening.

To answer your main question: I am not aware of any frameworks for this.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it seems like a good idea indeed. :)

Answer (score 2):

What is the best way to make the framework maintainable by the functional testers that are no technical people?

Cucumber is relatively simple so most folks can pick up the Gherkin step writing pretty quickly.

There are two main issues:

1) Who is going to write the step definitions for the actual code calls?

2) Who is going to maintain the test suite so that is remains DRY and maintainable.  Typically, without technical guidance the suite explodes into hundreds and thousands of duplicate cases. with many of them testing the backend 'through the UI'.  Seen this at *many* companies.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the input but how are we going to make it possible for these new features to be integrated within the app? The features are already written in Gherkin. Second point is not actually the case here because the scenarios are already predefined but executed manually today.